# Given an array of distinct integers , find 8 elements which sum up to a given Number?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Given an array of distinct integers , find 8 elements which sum up to a given Number.

Arr[] = [10,2,6,3,4,9,0,1,7,6,8,5,14,234,5645,1124]

Sum = 36

Answer: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

What's the best way to solve this with extra space and without extra space?

My solution:

Without Space: Have 8 nested for loops to add and find the solution, complexity, n^8.

With Space: How can we do it with extra space and what would be the time and space complexity? Can we do it in N^4 by creating N^4 sets of 4 elements each and saving in hash. Can we do better?

Comment: This is a well-studied problem. Do some research on the subset-sum problem.

Comment: the subset sum question doesn't ask for number of elements to be added for the sum, it only asks to find "a" set which matches the sum. If you agree to this, revert back the negative remark.

Comment: Usual practice for programmer's brain - slightly modify well-known algorithm to fit his needs.

Comment: With O(n) space you can bring down time to O(n^7), I don't think that with the N^4 sets is working.

Comment: I meant , create n^2 disjoint pairs from the given N elements. Space Needed till now O(N^2). Using those elements, create another N^2 disjoint pairs. (i.e. total N^4 sets). Space Needed till now O(N^4). Now save these elements in Hash. Space is still O(n^4). Now, just loop through this list, and if we find Sum - CurrentSet'sSum in hash, we have the answer. So total Time = O(N^4), Space = O(N^4).